# Finding a closed form for a given sequence

Tags: induction, closed-form

While studying induction, I came across this question where first I had to find closed form for this sequence:

$$g(i,j) =\cases{0,&$i = j = 0$\\
i, &$j = 0$\\
j,&$i = 0$\\
g(i-1,j) + g(i,j-1)& $i\geq1, j \geq1$}$$

I came to know the answer was$$ \frac{(i+j)!}{(i-1)! (j+1)!} + \frac{(i+j)!}{(i+1)! (j-1)!}$$

I was able to verify this using double induction but how to find a closed form for a sequence like this?
An informal proof would suffice.Please don't ignore.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: I understand but I still don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: To start with, math expressions should be surrounded by `$` signs.  I'll edit your post, and you can take a look at how I did it.  Don't edit yourself for a bit, or we'll clash.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will make sure next time my question is formatted properly:)

Comment: Please look at my edit.  No doubt it's not the best formatting possible, but it's a lot easier to read.  Don't try to control the spacing yourself; let MathJax do it.

Comment: Just do your best; people will help you out if you run into trouble.

Comment: Absolutely!Understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following grid graph, where each intersection is has a vertex. Then $g(i, j)$ is the number of ways to travel from the start node (green) to the end node (red) by moving only rightwards or downwards.

[image]

Why is this so? If you have learnt dynamic programming before, it is quite easy to see. Otherwise, I will try to explain. Label the green node $(i, j)$. When you move right, the label becomes $(i, j-1)$. When you move down, the label is $(i-1, j)$. Labelling all the nodes in this manner, we have that the missing node (indicated by the black circle) would have been labelled $(0, 0)$ and the red node labelled $(-1, -1)$.
To clear up some potential confusions, note that the indices of the bottommost row and the rightmost column are $-1$.

Let $f(i, j)$ be the number of ways to travel from vertex $(i, j)$ to the red node.
Then we have the recurrence relation $f(i, j) = f(i-1, j) + f(i, j-1)$. Also, it is easy to see the base cases all hold: $f(0, j) = j$ for all $j$, $f(i, 0) = i$ for all $i$, and since vertex $(0, 0)$ doesn't exist, so we just set $f(0, 0) = 0$.
This gives a recurrence for $f(i,j)$ which is precisely the same as your $g(i, j)$.

Now, lets compute a closed form for $f(i, j)$. To do this, imagine you add back the vertex $(0, 0)$ to get a extended grid. Then the number of paths $f(i,j)$ is the number of paths (from green to red) on the extended grid, minus the number of paths passing through $(0, 0)$. This is given by the formulas

\begin{align*}
{i+j+2 \choose i+1} - 2{i+j \choose i} 
&= \frac{(i+j+2)!}{(i+1)!(j+1)!} - 2\frac{(i+j)!}{i! j!} \\
&= \dotsm \\
&= \frac{(i+j)! \left((j(j+1) + i(i+1) \right)}{(i-1)!(j-1)!}
\end{align*}
which you can check equals to the formula you have given.